# How to release ionic 3 app to IOS in windows 10

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I want to publish my ionic 3 app to **IOS** in windows 10 environment.

Comment: please mark the answer that was right for you.

Answer (score 0):

https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/

iOS Devices

Unlike Android, iOS developers need to generate a provisioning profile to code sign their apps for testing. The good news is that, as of iOS9, you can develop and test your apps on your iOS device without a paid Apple Developer account. This is particularly great for developers who want to try out mobile development with Ionic, since it saves the cost but still provides a lot of the features of having a full Apple Developer account. For a full breakdown of the features included, check out Apple’s docs.
Requirements

- Xcode 7 or higher
- iOS 9
- A free Apple ID or paid Apple Developer account

---

I had a friend who once made and installation of iOS on his PC. It was a bad idea as it took a lot of effort and had to disable cpu cores in order to function. You can make an investigation though. I also consider running a vm a bad idea too but this is also doable.

Comment: Thanks for support

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there is no way to do that. You need a macOS environment, you can do the following:

- The easiest and the best way is to buy a macOS computer

Two other options are:

- Setting up a VM with a macOS but that is against all apples policies of course
- There are sites where you can rent a mac in the cloud but that can also be expensive.

So yeah, unfortunately the best way to test iOS apps is to buy a mac and an iphone.

Comment: Thanks for support.

Answer (score 0):

To build app for IOS you need Xcode and consequently use iOS.
It may try to use a VM, but this makes the process more complicated still.